# Python holding back the value from the previous execution

Tags: python

This is a program to find the roots of a quadratic equation, but when i execute the program more than once the values from the previous execution still remain in the list root. How can I clear it?

When I put `del root` in the function `quad()`, it gives an error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'root' referenced before assignment`. Why?

```py
import math
import cmath
root=[]
def roots(a:int,b:int,c:int):
    if ((b**2)-4*a*c)>=0:
        x1=(-b+(math.sqrt((b**2)-4*a*c)))/(2*a)
        x2=(-b-(math.sqrt((b**2)-4*a*c)))/(2*a)
    else:
        x1=(-b+cmath.sqrt((b**2)-4*a*c))/(2*a)
        x2=(-b-cmath.sqrt((b**2)-4*a*c))/(2*a)  
    root.append(x1)
    root.append(x2)
    return root

def quad():   
    a=int(input("enter the co-efficient of x^2-integer"))
    b=int(input("enter the co-efficient of x-integer"))
    c=int(input("enter the constant-integer"))
    roots(a,b,c)
    print(root)
    del root
```

Comment: How are you running this code? In an interactive Python session maybe?

Comment: Why don't you make `root` a local variable of `roots` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert `root` to a local variable,

```
import math
import cmath


def calculate_roots(a: int, b: int, c: int):
    roots = []
    if ((b ** 2) - 4 * a * c) >= 0:
        x1 = (-b + (math.sqrt((b ** 2) - 4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)
        x2 = (-b - (math.sqrt((b ** 2) - 4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)
    else:
        x1 = (-b + cmath.sqrt((b ** 2) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)
        x2 = (-b - cmath.sqrt((b ** 2) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)
    roots.append(x1)
    roots.append(x2)
    return roots


def quad():
    a = int(input("enter the co-efficient of x^2-integer"))
    b = int(input("enter the co-efficient of x-integer"))
    c = int(input("enter the constant-integer"))
    roots = calculate_roots(a, b, c)
```

Comment: thank you,that worked.But do you know why my code was giving an error??

Comment: You were storing the result in a global variable. And it was not getting initialized every time. That's why it was holding previous calculated result too.

Comment: Ok,but why was i unable to delete the list root with del root??it gave  -UnboundLocalError: local variable 'root' referenced before assignment-  doesn't del root come after a value assigned to the list root??.If i was able to delete this list whenever i call the function wouldn't the list be created again??